# Azure Functions cold start when the warm instance count is increasing beyond 1

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, cold-start

In Azure Functions consumption mode, is there any cold start when the warm instance count goes from 1 to N? I'm aware of cold starts that customers experience when there are no warm instances running. How does this work when the app is scaling beyond a single warm instance?

Answer (score 1):

When an app is already warm and scales to further instances they are taken from a pool of idle workers, the idle workers are kept so that the cold start down during scaling is very fast, personally I have not seen any missed connections during scaling of applications when done correctly, just make sure that your code is a small and quick to load as possible on the consumption plan and if your load varied a lot in short amount of time you might see that the consumption plan does not have enough to scale out but for most normal traffic patterns this is not an issue

Some very good reference documentation can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/?ref=msdn)